# What is a good WYSIWYG editor and wiki engine for making a long programming tutorial?

Tags: c++, wiki, source-code, wysiwyg

I would like to make a multi-page online tutorial that includes a lot of snippets of `C++ code`. I'm looking for something like the preview of source code provided by the programming-related StackExchange sites. What wiki-engine and associated editor is designed for this type of programming-centered content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) install and a plugin to facilitate the code highlighting. There are many options for that. Here's a rundown of some of them: http://blog.templatemonster.com/2011/04/15/wordpress-plugins-code-snippets-displaying/

Answer (score 0):

[WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) is awesome for comparing wikis. As for a Stack Exchange like feel, you're probably not going to see a slick live preview, or at least I haven't found one that will do this. It may be possible to set it up yourself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874646/which-stack-overflow-style-markdown-wmd-javascript-editor-should-i-use) might help you, and [this](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) is what Stack Exchange uses.

Comment: I'd love to see what you end up with by the way. I'd appreciate a ping when you've got something to show off. :)